# Is multiple inheritance in Perl and Java the same?

Tags: java, perl, inheritance

Is the multiple inheritance in Java and Perl the same?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no multiple inheritance in Java, but single inheritance + multiple interface implementation, while Perl does have multiple inheritance.

Comment: +1 for saying Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance. Not even through interfaces, because thats not we call inheritance, arguably.

Comment: Good way to remember that: bad puns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512/computer-language-puns-and-jokes/17578#17578

Answer (score 7):

Don't know about Perl, but Java only allows multiple inheritance of interface.  Only single-inheritance is allowed for implementation.

Answer (score 7):

No. Perl doesn't have interfaces, and Java only allows multiple inheritance through interfaces.

Comment: Actually the base perl object system hasn't got interfaces, but through additional extensions like Moose you can get roles which apparently are even better :)

Comment: That's a good point, I was only considering the core language, without CPAN modules.